Improve Pandas and Vectorization Performance on large dataset
CONTEXT
I have a large dataset (100-250mb) in a CSV file and need to assign groupings to the population of people.  The groupings are based on a dynamic ruleset defined in another CSV file.  For ease of reproduction, I've added sample data and sample 'rulesets' / query strings
DATA
 # Data looks like this:
 ID    Gender    Age     Country
 1     Male      60      USA
 2     Female    25      UK
 3     Male      30      Australia    

CURRENT CODE
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

query1 = '(Gender in ["Male","Female"]) & (Country=="USA")'
query2 = '(Country in ["USA", "UK"]) & (Gender=="Male")'
query3 = '(Age > 40) & (Gender=="Male")'

query_list = [query1, query2, query3]
query_names = ['USA', 'MALE_USA_UK', 'MALE_OVER_40']

def assign_name(row, id_list, name, column_list):
    id = row['ID']
    if name in column_list:
        if row[name] == 'Yes':
            return 'Yes'
    if str(id) in id_list:
        return 'Yes'
    return 'No'

# Create a dataframe with random data
data = {
    'ID': range(1, 101),
    'Gender': ['Male', 'Female'] * 50,
    'Age': np.random.randint(18, 70, size=100),
    'Country': ['USA', 'Canada', 'UK', 'Australia'] * 25
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
tmp = df.copy()

for query in query_list:
    name = query_names[query_list.index(query)]
    out = tmp.query(query)
        
    # Create a list of people that were derived in out.  These are 'yes'
    person_list = out['ID'].to_list()
    column_list = out.columns.to_list()

    # Give them a 'Yes' or 'No' based on them being in the 'out' df
    df[name] = df.apply(
            lambda row: assign_name(row, person_list, name, column_list), axis = 1)

PROBLEM
With larger datasets with 200k+ rows and 50+ different classification groups, this process takes a long time to run.  I often get the DataFrame is highly fragmented error on .insert.  I would like help building a solution that is quicker and more efficient.

I would give you four suggestions.
First, you're looping over all combinations of query_list and query_names. This means that for the MALE_USA_UK column, it evaluates every different query, and assigns it to the same column. The final result in that column will be the query from '(Age > 40) & (Gender=="Male")', the over-40 query, since that's what ran last. This looks like both a bug and a performance problem.
I think what you intended was to loop over pairs of queries/names, matching up queries and names at the same position. The Python builtin zip() can do this.
Example:
for query, name in zip(query_list, query_names):

Second, DataFrame.query() essentially does two things. It evaluates your boolean index using DataFrame.eval(), then uses DataFrame.loc[] to convert that boolean index into the rows that matched.
In the code after this, you are undoing the effects of DataFrame.loc[], by searching for matching values. Instead of doing DataFrame.loc[] and undoing it, it would be faster to use DataFrame.eval().
Example:
for query, name in zip(query_list, query_names):
    in_query = tmp.eval(query)

    # Give them a 'Yes' or 'No' based on in_query being true or false
    df[name] = np.where(in_query, 'Yes', 'No')

Third, I would suggest using booleans instead of Yes/No strings. Booleans are true/false values. They come with a long list of benefits.

Memory usage: A boolean uses about eight times less memory than a string.
Speed: Pandas has vectorized operations for boolean logic. In contrast, doing this with strings requires string comparison, which is slow.
Better syntax: It is easier to type df[df['MALE_USA_UK']] than it is to type df[df['MALE_USA_UK'] == 'Yes'].

Example:
for query, name in zip(query_list, query_names):
    in_query = tmp.eval(query)
    df[name] = in_query

The fourth suggestion pertains to your fragmentation warning.

I often get the DataFrame is highly fragmented error on .insert.

The reason why you get this warning is because of a Pandas internal structure called BlockManager. If you care about the details, you can read here about what this is and does. If you don't care, you can just use pd.concat() to solve the problem.
The way you can do that is to build up a list of new columns, then add them all at once using pd.concat(). This avoids fragmentation.
new_columns = []
    
for query, name in zip(query_list, query_names):
    in_query = df.eval(query)
    in_query.name = name
    new_columns.append(in_query)
    
df = pd.concat([df, *new_columns], axis=1)

Finally, here is the full re-written code based on all of these suggestions.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

query1 = '(Gender in ["Male","Female"]) & (Country=="USA")'
query2 = '(Country in ["USA", "UK"]) & (Gender=="Male")'
query3 = '(Age > 40) & (Gender=="Male")'

query_list = [query1, query2, query3]
query_names = ['USA', 'MALE_USA_UK', 'MALE_OVER_40']

# Create a dataframe with random data
data = {
    'ID': range(1, 101),
    'Gender': ['Male', 'Female'] * 50,
    'Age': np.random.randint(18, 70, size=100),
    'Country': ['USA', 'Canada', 'UK', 'Australia'] * 25
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

new_columns = []
    
for query, name in zip(query_list, query_names):
    in_query = df.eval(query)
    in_query.name = name
    new_columns.append(in_query)
    
df = pd.concat([df, *new_columns], axis=1)


A couple of things u can do here,

Create New Columns Based on Masks

Use proper vectorized operations to create new columns based on the precomputed masks. So something like -
result_df = df.copy()
for name, mask_ids in masks.items():
    result_df[name] = np.where(result_df['ID'].isin(mask_ids), 'Yes', 'No')
print(result_df)


Precompute
Boolean masks for each query once, instead of querying the DataFrame multiple times. For example - You can define queries, create a DataFrame with random data and then initialize a dict for holding mask for each 1 query mask.


Can you explain how the masks variable should be defined?

@NickODell See the general approach to using masks is that they are essentially filters that allow you to quickly identify rows in a dataframe that meet certain criteria(defined), so for example we create a boolean mask to identify which rows in the DataFrame have ID that match in the mask_ids list. Now can use np.where to assign 'Yes' to rows where the mask is True and 'No' where it is False, updating the name column in the result_df DataFrame. Code example - result_df[name] = np.where(df['ID'].isin(mask_ids), 'Yes', 'No')
